# Having trouble with the "Blocked by your Organization" in Windows 11 with Internet Download Manager

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11

I was running Internet Download Manager (IDM) on my Lenovo ThinkPad Laptop with Windows 11 Pro using Chrome browser.  From the day I purchased the laptop, it has never been connected to an organization.  This is my personal laptop and only used as such and I am retired.

I purchased IDM near the end of 2023.  It was running great until 1 1/2 weeks ago.  That is when I got the "Blocked by your Organization" error. I am not sure which came first before this problem started. There was a Windows 11 and a Chrome update that occurred very close together.

After the restart, IDM quit working.  I downloaded and installed the IDM software as described by their instructions on their website.
After it started, I restarted the browser and tried again with no help, restarted the laptop with no help, uninstalled and reinstalled the software with no help, and ran a virus scan that was clean. I contacted IDM tech support by email multiple times and they seem to have no clue and are less than helpful. I have done a lot of the suggestions in this thread, and none helped.

I am reaching out to the group to see if there is anything else to try. Currently, I am at a loss. I explained all of this to tech support and asked when there might be a patch or version. Their tech support did get back with me and told me it wasn't there problem because I am apparently the only one to complain.

So if anyone knows how to remove the Organization Error, I would be interested in your thoughts.

Comment: The "Blocked by your Organization" error is badly worded, in the sense that the "Organization" can be yourself, having changed some setting in Windows that blocks IDM. Questions: (1) When exactly do you get the error and can you add a screenshot of it to your post. (2) Does the desktop version of IDM work? (3) Try to temporarily disable your antivirus and firewall  and test IDM (return them after testing).

Comment: Hey harrymc. Not sure how to upload screenshot. I haven't intentionally made Win 11 changes that I know of.  (1) I have completely deleted, as best as I can tell, IDM from my laptop and downloaded it again from their website.  When installing it this time, I remembered to run it as 'admin'.  It installs the program OK, but when I try to install the extension in Chrome, that is when I get the error of "Blocked by your Organization".  I have tried turning off safe mode in Google with no help. (2) My laptop is my desktop.  My desktop is 15 years old. (3) I will try this now and get back to you.

Comment: That's probably because you installed as admin something designed to be run by a regular user. And sorry for wasting your money in crappy software for which there are dozens of similar or better free alternatives.

Comment: On additional note: [Free Download manager](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) is quite good.